# How to include a style sheet

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

**I am starting to program in HTML and CSS**. I have this very simple line of code and I try to add bootstrap, but I can't make the button have style that the style sheet adds to it.

So the button doesn't show me with its respective style, so
I want to know what I am doing wrong?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Name of the website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is an example of a paragraph.</p>
    <p>¡Hello world!</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger daw!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any Java?  Java and Javascript are not the same language.  (and this is mostly HTML).

Comment: Your query is purely html and css related. add html tag and remove java tag. @SO User try to be little kind to new user before down-vote. it's discouraging.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is for a task that has been left to me, I had to ask a question in a forum. @Nexevis

Comment: @SSP: I agree, a constructive comment could be useful than a down vote (especially to a new -user).@Adonay: This question is not related to java, are you tasked to ask any question or specifically this one, as it is?

Answer (score 1):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Maybe this way the code can help you</h1>
  <p>This is a example of paragrafh</p>
  <p>!Hello world!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to use bootstrap and Javascript in your HTML.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```